# How can I change the title of a Wikipedia article?

Tags: wikipedia

It appears to me that the title of [this page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_division) must be changed from "Euclidean Division" to "Euclidean Division Lemma". So, how can I do this given that the "edit" option of Wikipedia only allows to edit the content of the page and not its title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To rename a page, you need to "Move" it.

The [Move](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:MovePage/Euclidean_division) link can be found under the "More" menu (assuming you've not customized the user interface). <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> is the keyboard shortcut.

The advantage of moving the article is that it leaves a redirect behind, so that all of the previous links don't break.

See: [Wikipedia: Moving a page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Moving_a_page) for more information.

While Wikipedia encourages people to "be bold", you'd do well to discuss the change in the [article's talk page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talk:Euclidean_division) first, otherwise you may find your move quickly reverted. Especially since I see several previous discussions about the name of the article that settled on the current name as a compromise.

Comment: To expand on this: on the English Wikipedia, only registered users who have achieved [autoconfirmed status](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:User_access_levels#Autoconfirmed_users) (4 day old account with at least 10 edits) can move pages.